# Selenium CSS Locator for span text inside nested divs

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

Anyone know the css selector statement in selenium (webdriver - java) in the following code to get 'text2'?

```
<div class="firstclass"> 
<br> 
<p id="someid" class="secondclass"> 
<span>text1 </span> 
<span>text2</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same similar issue today, and i was able to retrieve the text by using the `div.getText`, because in my situation the `<Div><Span>text</Span>` completed `</Div>` the text present between span was not available when i tried with `span.getText()`... might be the same with your case.

Answer (score 1):

`div p span + span` should work for that structure.

Comment: I could not get that to work. Also I have tried span:nth-child(2) I think it is because this is a div nested in like 20 other divs. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The structure above the sample you gave should not influential on that selection. You can try use Id from p element: p#someid span+span

Answer (score 0):

Try it with xpath

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='firstclass']/span[2]).getText()
```

Comment: no, you can get this text 2 with this Webdriver-command by using xpath.

Comment: Why not? Just try it please it should work. He wanted to get the "text2" and this command gives him the "text2" in his code.

Comment: Because there's no table in his HTML at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here

Text1 = css=#someid > span
Text2 = css=#someid > span + span

OR

Text2 = css=#someid > span:nth-of-type(2)

Text2 = css=#someid > span:nth-child(2)